# How to fix htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am follwing this bootsnip code in https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/BE93p
for creating a dynamic table in bootstrab,  it insert a new filed after clicking add row button and dynamically calculate the total price after filling the inputs.

but I git this error after inserting a new row?!

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laundry\vendor\blade-ui-kit\blade-ui-kit\resources\views\components\forms\inputs\input.blade.php)
```

the Blade page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center"> # </th>
                    <th class="text-center"> Product </th>
                    <th class="text-center"> Qty </th>
                    <th class="text-center"> Price </th>
                    <th class="text-center"> Total </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price' class="form-control price" step="0.00" min="0"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</button>
            <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic_total">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Sub Total</th>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='sub_total' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" id="sub_total" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Tax</th>
                    <td class="text-center"><div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tax" placeholder="0">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Tax Amount</th>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='tax_amount' id="tax_amount" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Grand Total</th>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='total_amount' id="total_amount" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $("#add_row").click(function(){b=i-1;
            $('#addr'+i).html($('#addr'+b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i+1);
            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
            i++;
        });
        $("#delete_row").click(function(){
            if(i>1){
                $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
                i--;
            }
            calc();
        });

        $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change',function(){
            calc();
        });
        $('#tax').on('keyup change',function(){
            calc_total();
        });


    });

    function calc()
    {
        $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
            var html = $(this).html();
            if(html!='')
            {
                var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
                var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
                $(this).find('.total').val(qty*price);

                calc_total();
            }
        });
    }

    function calc_total()
    {
        total=0;
        $('.total').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
        tax_sum=total/100*$('#tax').val();
        $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
        $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum+total).toFixed(2));
    }
```

please help me to fix that error

Answer (score 0):

Had fixed this issue simmply by adding type="button"
in the button tags

```
  <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</button>
            <button type="button" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</button>
```